# Отправить post запрос с получением куки

Tags: php, c#, post, cookie

Доброго времени суток, знатоки! 
Сделала авторизацию с сессией на php, в приложении пытаюсь отправить post запрос на сервер, для авторизации.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне принять куки с сервера, дабы при входе в программу не приходилось вводить логин и пароль, или может быть есть какой то более гуманный способ? Спасибо!

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection();
            values["login"] = loginBox.Text;
            values["password"] = passwordBox.Password;
            var response = client.UploadValues("http://127.0.0.1/login", values);
            var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
            if (true)
            {// something}
        }
```

Comment: использовать куки на клиенте, написанном на шарпах - моветон, если честно. 
для подобных целей существует rest api. 
Посмотрите в сторону авторизации через jwt токены. 
Логика такова: 
С клиента на сервер идёт запрос на авторизацию, в котором передаются логин и пароль. С сервера возвращается токен, который сохраняется клиентом, и в дальнейшем используется при всех запросах. При повторном входе в приложение, в котором существует токен, отправляется запрос на проверку. Если всё ок - используем сохранённый токен, если нет - получаем новый и сохранямем

Comment: Есть примерный код? Я не представляю, как работать с подобными функциями

Comment: код на шарпе, или на пхп ? 
С пхп не помогу, т.к. я использую только сишарп (клиент и сервер сайд)

Comment: Решила иначе, при создании сессии делаю вывод PHPSESSID значения, далее работаю с ним. Это значение может как раз являться токеном, только как сделать проверку на созданную сессию по этому значению?

Comment: сессии и jwt токены - принципиально разные вещи, первые не предназначены для использования из клиентских приложений => айди сессии неправильно использовать как jwt. 

отвечая на вопрос, как их (айди) можно проверить. хм... не знаю даже. ну можно извлекать её из куков и попытаться проверить актуальность сессии

Comment: Именно это я и пытаюсь сейчас получить из кукисов

Answer (score 1):

Это класс взят [с английского stackoverflaw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29479390/8411541)

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
  public CookieAwareWebClient()
  {
    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    this.ResponseCookies = new CookieCollection();
  }

  public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }
  public CookieCollection ResponseCookies { get; set; }

  protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
  {
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
    request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
    return request;
  }

  protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
  {
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)base.GetWebResponse(request);
    this.ResponseCookies = response.Cookies;
    return response;
  }
}
```

и он там был не раз скопипастен в различных вариантах)

и использование в вашем коде

```
using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
    {
        var values = new NameValueCollection();
        values["login"] = loginBox.Text;
        values["password"] = passwordBox.Password;
        var response = client.UploadValues("http://127.0.0.1/login", values);
        var phpSessionId = ResponseCookies["PHPSESSID"]
        if (phpSessionId != null)
        {// something}
    }
```